# Power shell command picks 2 files instead of just one

Tags: powershell

I'm facing a weird issue with my script.

I have 2 files:
OBTM_OUTCOME_GFM_20150519164709_1.end
and
OBTM_OUTCOME_GFM_20150818142145_11.end

I'm suppose to pick only the file with the minimum MinKey , where MinKey  is the digits after the last underscore.
For the first file, MinKey  is 1,
for the second MinKey   is  11.

S3PathName is the S3 bucket and it's the same for both of the file.
InputBaseFileName = OBTM_OUTCOME_GFM,
and MinKey was found and it is 1.

When I set the below command, I get both of the files, while I'm only interested in the first one:

```
Get-S3Object -BucketName $S3BucketName -KeyPrefix $S3PathName | 
Where-Object {$_.Key -Like "$S3PathName/$InputBaseName*$MinKey.*"}.....
```

Is it possible that asterisk is not functioning as I think it should?
Thanks

Comment: How are you defining $MinKey?

Comment: `-Like "$S3PathName/$InputBaseName*_$MinKey.*"`

Comment: Thanks @PetSerAl! That actually solved it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PetSerAl's solution is correct, the * allows any number of characters (including 0).

If you trim out everything except the end:

_1.end
_11.end

and apply the query `$_ -like *1.end` it will return both files, because * can mean both "_" and "_1".

By adding the _ to the query: `$_ -like *_1.end` you are ensuring you are only checking for a FULL match after the _ rather than allowing additional characters.

Substitute "1" with `$MinKey and add in the rest:

```
Where-Object {$_.Key -Like "$S3PathName/$InputBaseName*_$MinKey.*"}
```